# I need a shell script to convert a csv file into pipe (|) delimited file by keeping the commas inside the enclosing quotes

Tags: csv

Sample File (test.csv):

```
"PRCD-15234","CDOC","12","JUN-20-2016 17:00:00","title, with commas, ","Y!##!"
"PRCD-99999","CDOC","1","Sep-26-2016 17:00:00","title without comma","Y!##!"
```

Output file:

```
PRCD-15234|CDOC|12|JUN-20-2016 17:00:00|title, with commas, |Y!##!
PRCD-99999|CDOC|1|Sep-26-2016 17:00:00|title without comma|Y!##!
```

My script (doe not work) is below:

```
while IFS="," read f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6; 
do  
    echo $f1|$f2|$f3|$f4|$f5|$f6;  
done < test.csv
```

Comment: You should probably use a tool that more correctly parses rather than just trying to tokenize.  Are you open to solutions that use other languages like perl or python?

Comment: Thanks for fixing the format. Unfortunately no perl or python. It can only be a shell script using basic unix/linux commands

Comment: @user204362 perl isn't as universal as awk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(generate output) | sed -e 's/","/|/g' -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//'`

or

`sed -e 's/","/|/g' -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//' $file`

For the 3 expressions:

- `-e 's/","/|/g'`  =  replace all the delimiters `","` with the new delimiter `|`
- `-e 's/^"//'`  = remove the leading `"` mark
- `-e 's/"$//'`  = remove the trailing end of line `"` mark

This will preserve any quote marks that happen to be in the title, as long as they don't match the initial delimiter pattern `","`

Answer (score 1):

How about
`cat test.csv | sed 's/\",\"/|/g' | sed 's/\"//g'`

Assuming the data in the your file is like the way shown above, (I am not taking corner cases into consideration.)
But above worked for me.

Comment: [UUOC](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html)

Answer (score 0):

This one handles embedded string delimiters:

```
$ cat /tmp/bla
"PRCD-15234","CDOC","12","JUN-20-2016 17:00:00","title, with commas, ","Y!##!"
"PRCD-99999","CDOC","1","Sep-26-2016 17:00:00","title without comma","Y!##!"
"PRCD-99999","CDOC","1","Sep-26-2016 17:00:00","embedded\",delimiters\",","Y!##!"
```

`sed -E 's/"(([^"]*(\\")?)*)",/\1|/g;s/"|(([^"]*(\\")?)*)"/\1/g'`

→

```
PRCD-15234|CDOC|12|JUN-20-2016 17:00:00|title, with commas, |Y!##!
PRCD-99999|CDOC|1|Sep-26-2016 17:00:00|title without comma|Y!##!
PRCD-99999|CDOC|1|Sep-26-2016 17:00:00|embedded\",delimiters\",|Y!##!
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script does not work since it does not attempt to parse the quoted fields the way a CSV parser would.  This means it sees the quoted fields' commas as delimiters.

---

Using the two CSV-aware tools `csvformat` (from [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) and [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`):

```bash
$ csvformat -D '|' file
PRCD-15234|CDOC|12|JUN-20-2016 17:00:00|title, with commas, |Y!##!
PRCD-99999|CDOC|1|Sep-26-2016 17:00:00|title without comma|Y!##!
```

```bash
$ mlr --csv --ofs pipe cat file
PRCD-15234|CDOC|12|JUN-20-2016 17:00:00|title, with commas, |Y!##!
PRCD-99999|CDOC|1|Sep-26-2016 17:00:00|title without comma|Y!##!
```